# What is the physics principle behind Helicone (wood toy)?

Tags: kinematics, education, aerodynamics

There is kind of toy "Helicone" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkmBLPHGp0E), It is composited with one base, one axle and many co-axle leaf-pairs.

When rotating it in a direction and suddenly stops, the angle of all leaves will be concentrated.

However, if rotating it in the opposite direction, all the leaves will distributed uniformly among all the angles.

The toy is made with pure wood except the axle.

Why it can achieve such effect? What is the physics principle behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mechanism between each set of 'leaf pairs'

[image]

that allows the pair above to rotate slightly further than the one underneath.

The image was from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9UUM7Umruc) youtube clip 'How to make a Helicone'.